# Nonzero elements in localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I have a very basic question that's been vexing me. Let $a\in A$ be a nonzero element of a Noetherian ring. Then $a$ lies in some maximal ideal $M$. Consider the localization $A_M$ at that maximal ideal. Is it true then that the element $\frac{a}{1}$ is nonzero in $A_M$? The text I'm reading (Milne's Algebraic Geometry) seems to say so (Proposition 1.16, page 18).

I was thinking that if $\frac{a}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$, then this implies that $ta=0$ for some $t\in A\setminus M$.

Comment: This is not true. Consider the ring $k\times k$, $k$ a field, and $M= k\times\{0\}$. In $A_M$, $(0,1)$ is invertible, so that $(0,1)\times (a,0) = (0,0)$ for all $a\in k$ implies that $(a,0) = 0$ in $A_M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, this is not true, with an explicit counterexample given by $A= k\times k$ for some field $k$, and $M= k\times\{0\}$.

However, this is not what Milne claims : in his text, $M$ is a maximal ideal containing $\{b \mid ba = 0\}$, but in particular, $a$ is rarely in there (sometimes it is). But because of this, any $t$ as you describe will have to be in $M$.